# How do I make an object oriented search button?

Tags: java, sql, swing, oop, search

My goal is to create a connections class and use it in another class to write my query

Here is that class:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Connections {

   private static final String DB_adress="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/data_base_test";
   private static final String DB_USER="root";
   private static final String DB_PASS="12345";

   public static Connection getConnections(){
       Connection connection=null;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        connection=DriverManager.getConnection(DB_adress,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
    } 
catch (SQLException throwables) {
        throwables.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return connection;
   }
}
```

This class return connections and now in the query class I use this class to write the query:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class query {

    public static int save (String usernam,String pass,String email){
    int status=0;
    try {
        Connection connection=Connections.getConnections();
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement= connection.prepareStatement( "insert into moshakhasat(username, pass, email) VALUES (?,?,?)");
        preparedStatement.setString(1,usernam);
        preparedStatement.setString(2,pass);
        preparedStatement.setString(3,email);
        status=preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        connection.close();
    } catch (SQLException throwables) {
        throwables.printStackTrace();
    }
    return status;
    }

    public static boolean search(String pass) {
        boolean status = false;
        try {
            Connection connection = Connections.getConnections();
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("select *from moshakhasat where pass=?");
            preparedStatement.setString(1, pass);

            ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            status = resultSet.next();
        } catch (SQLException throwables) {
            throwables.printStackTrace();
        }
        return status;
    }

    public static int delete(String pass){
        int status=0;
        try {
            Connection connection= Connections.getConnections();
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement=connection.prepareStatement("delete from moshakhasat where pass=?");
            preparedStatement.setString(1,pass);
            status=preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            connection.close();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return status;
    }
}
```

As you see this class has a different part in one part you can save your information.

In another part you can search another you can delete query and I use this class in my main class that has an interface using Swing that is called form class.

Here is the form class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Form {

    private JLabel Userlbl;
    private JLabel passlbl;
    public JTextField usertxt;
    private JPasswordField passtxt;
    private JTextField emailtxt;
    private JButton serchbtn;
    private JLabel emaillbl;
    private JButton sabtbtn;
    private JButton deletebtn;
    public JPanel panel;
    private JLabel lbluser;
    private JLabel lblpass;
    private Object Form;

    public Form() {
        serchbtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                String pass= passtxt.getText();

                boolean j=query.search(pass);
                if (j==true){
                    usertxt.setText("");
                    emailtxt.setText("");
                }
            }
        });
        sabtbtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Pass pass1=new Pass();
               User user= new User();
              boolean result=user.validations(usertxt.getText());
                boolean result2=pass1.validator(passtxt.getText());
              if (result==true&&result2==true){
                   String name=usertxt.getText();
                  String pass= passtxt.getText();
                  String email= emailtxt.getText();
                  int i= query.save(name,pass,email);
                  JOptionPane.showInputDialog(Form,"ATELAAT SABT SHOD");
            } else{ lbluser.setText("user name is unacceptable");
                usertxt.setText("");
                lblpass.setText("paas is invalid");
                passtxt.setText(""); String name=usertxt.getText();}
            }
        });
        deletebtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int v=query.delete(passtxt.getText());
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog(JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE+"KARBAR HAZF SHOD");
            }
        });
    }
}

class Main extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("email sender");
                    frame.setContentPane(new Form().panel);
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

As you can see in this class we have 3 buttons: save, delete and search.
The problem is with the search button.

```
  serchbtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    
                    String pass= passtxt.getText();
    
                    boolean j=query.search(pass);
                    if (j==true){
                        usertxt.setText("");
                        emailtxt.setText("");
                    }
                }
            });
```

When I press this button it should get the password and search the database and show the result in the text field but I can;t use it in query class.

Here is the code in query class:

```
  public static boolean search(String pass) {
            boolean status = false;
            try {
                Connection connection = Conetions.getConections();
                PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("select *from moshakhasat where pass=?");
                preparedStatement.setString(1, pass);
                ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
                status = resultSet.next();
            } catch (SQLException throwables) {
                throwables.printStackTrace();
            }

            return status;
```

But I can't set the text field in my `Form` class with the query that is searched.

Comment: I see you have UI code (Swing) and DB code, where is your problem? Is it not showing the text? Then the DB part is not needed, if the error is in the DB connection, then the UI part is irrelevant. For better help sooner create a proper [mre] that demonstrates your issue. If it's Swing related (i.e. the database part works correctly), hardcode the of the password).

Comment: Also, there's no need for you to add multiple empty lines between your code, empty lines are just for separating code into blocks that make sense together, if you leave an empty line between every other line, the code becomes harder to read. Btw, give your variables meaningful names `j = quary.seach(pass)` could be something like `isPasswordCorrect = ...` and please follow naming conventions, `FirstWordUpperCasedClass`, `firstWordLowerCasedVariable`, `firstWordLowerCasedMethod(...)` and `ALL_WORDS_UPPER_CASED_CONSTANT`

Comment: *"when i press this botton it should get the password and search the data base and show the result in text fild"* What result and in which text field? All you're doing before this comment (which should have `//` before that text) is set the textfields to empty, both `user` and `email`

Comment: I'd combine your Connection and Query classes into one SQL class.  Have you tested each class and method individually to narrow down the text field problem?